# Node editor library

Tags: javascript

I wrote a node editor library which can be found [here](https://github.com/depuits/ned). What can I do to make the code more readable and maintainable? I'd like to stay in plain javascript and keep a single reference to use the library.

```js
"use strict";

/**************************
 * Main object
 **************************/
var Ned = {
 create(svg) {
  var editor = Object.create(Ned);
  editor.init(svg);

  return editor;
 },

 init(svg) {
  this.svg = null;

  this.snapping = 0;

  this.singleInputs = false;
  this.singleOutputs = false;

  this.dragConn = null;

  if (!(svg instanceof SVGElement)) {
   svg = document.querySelector(svg);
  }
  this.svg = svg;
  this.svg.ns = this.svg.namespaceURI;

  // group for all node elements
  this.nodegroup = document.createElementNS(this.svg.ns, "g");
  this.nodegroup.setAttribute("class", "Nodegroup");
  this.svg.appendChild(this.nodegroup);

  // group to draw the paths above the nodes
  this.pathGroup = document.createElementNS(this.svg.ns, "g");
  this.pathGroup.setAttribute("class", "PathGroup");
  this.svg.appendChild(this.pathGroup);
 },

 createNode(title) {
  var n = Object.create(Ned.Node);
  n.init (this, title);

  return n;
 },

 screenToWorld(pos) {
  return pos;
 }
};

/**************************
 * Node Object
 **************************/
Ned.Node = {
 init(ned, sTitle) {
  this.editor = ned;
  this.inputs = [];
  this.outputs = [];

  // ****************** root ******************
  this.eRoot = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("class", "NodeContainer");
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
  ned.nodegroup.appendChild(this.eRoot);
  this.width = 200;
  this.height = 100;

  var headerSize = 24;

  // ****************** background ******************
  this.eBack = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "rect");
  this.eBack.setAttribute("class", "Background");
  this.eBack.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  this.eBack.setAttribute("height", "100%");
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eBack);

  // ****************** header ******************
  this.eHeader = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "g");
  this.eHeader.setAttribute("class", "Header");
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eHeader);
  this.eHeader.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.beginNodeDrag (e); });

  this.eHeaderBack = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "rect");
  this.eHeaderBack.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  this.eHeaderBack.setAttribute("height", headerSize);
  this.eHeader.appendChild(this.eHeaderBack);
  
  this.eHeaderText = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "text");
  this.eHeaderText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sTitle));
  this.eHeaderText.setAttribute("x", "50%");
  this.eHeaderText.setAttribute("y", headerSize - 4); // padding to the bottom text
  this.eHeader.appendChild(this.eHeaderText);

  // ****************** foreign objects ******************
  this.eForeign = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "foreignObject");
  this.eForeign.setAttribute("x", "16");
  this.eForeign.setAttribute("y", headerSize);
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eForeign);

  // ****************** inputs and outputs ******************
  this.eInputs = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
  this.eInputs.setAttribute("class", "Inputs");
  this.eInputs.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
  this.eInputs.setAttribute("x", "0%");
  this.eInputs.setAttribute("y", headerSize);
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eInputs);

  this.eOutputs = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
  this.eOutputs.setAttribute("class", "Outputs");
  this.eOutputs.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
  this.eOutputs.setAttribute("x", "100%");
  this.eOutputs.setAttribute("y", headerSize);
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eOutputs);

  // ****************** foreign object test ******************
  this.eSelect = document.createElement("select");
  this.eForeign.appendChild(this.eSelect);

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
   var eOption = document.createElement("option");
   eOption.text = "test " + i;
   this.eSelect.appendChild(eOption);
  }
 },

 addInput(name) {
  var o = Object.create (Ned.Connector);
  this.inputs.push(o);
  o.init(this, name, true);
  return o;
 },

 addOutput(name) {
  var o = Object.create (Ned.Connector);
  this.outputs.push(o);
  o.init(this, name, false);
  return o;
 },

 updatePaths() {
  for (let c of this.inputs) c.updatePaths();
  for (let c of this.outputs) c.updatePaths();
 },

 get position() {
  return {
   x: this.eRoot.getAttribute("x"),
   y: this.eRoot.getAttribute("y")
  };
 },
 set position(pos) {
  if (this.editor.snapping) {
   var snp = this.editor.snapping;
   pos.x = Math.round(pos.x / snp) * snp;
   pos.y = Math.round(pos.y / snp) * snp;
  }

  this.eRoot.setAttribute("x", pos.x);
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("y", pos.y);
  this.updatePaths();
 },

 get width() {
  return this.eRoot.getAttribute("width");
 },
 set width(v) {
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("width", v);
 },

 get height() {
  return this.eRoot.getAttribute("height");
 },
 set height(v) {
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("height", v);
 },

 toTop() {
  this.editor.nodegroup.removeChild(this.eRoot);
  this.editor.nodegroup.appendChild(this.eRoot);
 },

 beginNodeDrag(e) {
  // we can only drag when the left mouse button is pressed
  if (e.button != 0) {
   return;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();

  this.toTop();
  var pos = this.position;
  var screenPos = this.editor.screenToWorld({ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY });
  var offsetX = pos.x - screenPos.x;
  var offsetY = pos.y - screenPos.y;

  var onNodeDragMouseMove = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   var screenPos = this.editor.screenToWorld({ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY });
   this.position = { x: screenPos.x + offsetX, y: screenPos.y + offsetY };
  };

  var onNodeDragMouseUp = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
   e.preventDefault();

   window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onNodeDragMouseMove);
   window.removeEventListener("mouseup",  onNodeDragMouseUp);
  };

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", onNodeDragMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", onNodeDragMouseUp);
 }
};

/**************************
 * Node Connector Object
 **************************/
Ned.Connector = {
 init(node, name, isInput) {
  this.node = node;
  this.isInput = isInput;
  this.paths = [];

  var neRoot = isInput ? node.eInputs : node.eOutputs;

  // ****************** root ******************
  this.eRoot = document.createElementNS(this.editor.svg.ns, "svg");
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("class", isInput ? "Input" : "Output");
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
  neRoot.appendChild(this.eRoot);

  // ****************** text ******************
  this.eText = document.createElementNS(this.editor.svg.ns, "text");
  this.eText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eText);

  // ****************** dot ******************
  this.eDot = document.createElementNS(this.editor.svg.ns, "circle");
  this.eDot.ref = this; // we set the refference on the object we want to be able to connect to
  this.eDot.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.beginConnDrag(e); });
  this.eDot.addEventListener("mouseenter", (e) => { this.addHoverClass(); });
  this.eDot.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e) => { this.removeHoverClass(); });
  this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eDot);

  this.updatePosition();
 },

 addHoverClass() {
  var conn = this.editor.dragConn;
  if (!conn || (this.isInput === conn.isInput)) return;

  // we only add the class if we are dragging and the dragging connector isn't the same type of this connector
  this.eDot.setAttribute("class", "ConnHover"); 
 },
 removeHoverClass() {
  // on mouse leave we'll always remove the class
  this.eDot.removeAttribute("class");
 },

 updatePosition() {
  var rect = this.eRoot.getBoundingClientRect();

  var i = this.index;
  var y = (rect.height) + (rect.height * 1.5 * i)
  this.eRoot.setAttribute("y", y);
 },

 updatePaths() {
  for(let p of this.paths) p.update();
 },
 addPath(path) {
  if (this.hasSinglePath) {
   // destroy all current paths
   for(let p of this.paths) p.destroy();

   // clear the array
   this.paths = [];
  }

  this.paths.push(path);
 },
 removePath(path) {
  var index = this.paths.indexOf(path);
  if(index != -1) {
   this.paths.splice(index, 1);
  }
 },

 get editor() {
  return this.node.editor;
 },

 get index() {
  var list = (this.isInput) ? this.node.inputs : this.node.outputs;
  return list.indexOf(this);
 },

 get hasSinglePath() {
  return (this.isInput) ? this.editor.singleInputs : this.editor.singleOutputs;
 },
 get position() {
  var rect = this.eDot.getBoundingClientRect();
  // we need to keep the svg position in mind
  // and center it 
  var screenPos = {
   x: rect.left + (rect.width / 2),
   y: rect.top + (rect.height / 2)
  };
  return this.editor.screenToWorld(screenPos);
 },

 // path parameter is optional and a path is created if none is supplied
 connectTo(conn, path) {
  if (this.isInput === conn.isInput) {
   //can't connect 2 inputs or 2 outputs
   if (path) path.destroy();
   return false;
  }

  if (!path) {
   var path = Object.create(Ned.Path);
   path.init(this);
  }
  path.setFinalConn(conn);

  // check if we don't already have a path like this
  if (this.paths.find((p) => path.equals(p))) {
   // this path already exists so delete it
   path.destroy();
   return false;
  } 

  // remember the new path
  //add path to conn paths list to update it
  this.addPath(path);
  conn.addPath(path);
  return true;
 },

 beginConnDrag(e) {
  // we can only drag when the left mouse button is pressed
  if (e.button != 0) {
   return;
  }

  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();

  this.editor.dragConn = this;
  var path = Object.create(Ned.Path);
  path.init(this);

  var onConnDragMouseMove = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();
   var mouseOffset = 3; // this offset is so the path isn't under the mouse when we release it. Else it isn't possible to get the underlying connector
   var screenPos = this.editor.screenToWorld({ x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY });
   var pos = { x: screenPos.x, y: screenPos.y + mouseOffset };
   path.updateWithPos(pos);
  }
  
  var onConnDragMouseUp = (e) => {
   e.stopPropagation();
   e.preventDefault();

   this.editor.dragConn = null;
   var conn = e.target.ref; // get the saved refence to connect
   if (Ned.Connector.isPrototypeOf(conn)) {
    this.connectTo(conn, path);
    conn.removeHoverClass(); // we've stopped dragging so we'll make sure the hover class is removed
   } else {
    path.destroy();
   }

   window.removeEventListener("mousemove", onConnDragMouseMove);
   window.removeEventListener("mouseup", onConnDragMouseUp);
  };

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", onConnDragMouseMove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", onConnDragMouseUp);
 }
};

/**************************
 * Node path Object
 **************************/
Ned.Path = {
 init(conn) {
  this.editor = conn.editor;
  this.input = conn.isInput ? conn : null;
  this.output = conn.isInput ? null : conn;

  this.ePath = document.createElementNS(this.editor.svg.ns, "path");
  this.ePath.setAttribute("class", "Path");  
  this.ePath.addEventListener("click", (e) => { this.onClicked(e); });

  this.editor.pathGroup.appendChild(this.ePath);

  var pos = conn.position;
  this.updateWithPos(pos);
 },

 destroy() {
  if (this.input) this.input.removePath(this);
  if (this.output) this.output.removePath(this);
  this.editor.pathGroup.removeChild(this.ePath);
  this.ePath = null;
 },

 setFinalConn(conn) {
  // if the input is set then set the output and vice versa
  if (this.input) this.output = conn;
  else this.input = conn;

  this.update();
 },

 equals(p) {
  return this.input === p.input && this.output === p.output;
 },

 onClicked(e) {
  // we can only drag when the left mouse button is pressed
  if (e.button != 0) {
   return;
  }
  
  this.destroy();
 },

 update() {
  this.updateWithPos ((this.input || this.output).position);
 },
 updateWithPos(pos) {
  var pos1 = this.output ? this.output.position : pos;
  var pos2 = this.input ? this.input.position : pos;
  this.setCurve (pos1.x, pos1.y, pos2.x, pos2.y);
 },

 setCurve(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var dif = Math.abs(x1 - x2) / 1.5,
   str = "M" + x1 + "," + y1 + " C" + //MoveTo
    (x1 + dif) + "," + y1 + " " + //First Control Point
    (x2 - dif) + "," + y2 + " " + //Second Control Point
    (x2) + "," + y2;    //End Point

  this.ePath.setAttribute('d', str);
 }
}
```